# How can I comment out some HTML code defined into the return() method of a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, javascript-framework

I am very new in ReactJS and I am facing this problem: how to comment out some HTML code defined into the **render()** method?

For example I have a **component** like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { term: '' };

    }

    render() {
        //return <input onChange={this.onInputChange} /> ;
        return (
            <div>
                
                <input onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })} />
                Value of the input: {this.state.term}
                
            </div>
        );
    }

    /*
    onInputChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);

    }*/

}

export default SearchBar;
```

I tried to comment out a section of the html returned by the **render()** method in this way:

```
render() {
    //return <input onChange={this.onInputChange} /> ;
    return (
        <div>
            
            <!-- <input onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })} /> -->
            <!--Value of the input: {this.state.term} -->

            <p>I want to see only this !!</p>
            
        </div>
    );
}
```

but it is wrong.

What am I missing? How can I comment out some HTML from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSX files you can use block comments inside of curly braces, e.g. `{/* My comment */}`.

In your case:

```
render() {
    //return <input onChange={this.onInputChange} /> ;
    return (
        <div>
            
            {/* <input onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })} /> */}
            {/*-Value of the input: {this.state.term} */}

            <p>I want to see only this !!</p>
            
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do It as you would in js

```
<div>
{/*
<div/>

*/}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 {/* <input onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })} /> */}
 {/*-Value of the input: {this.state.term} */}
```

Inside the `render block`, we must use the multi-line comments in curly braces {/* */}.

This is a [detailed ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-write-comments-in-reactjs/)